# How can I specify the C++ version to use with Xcode?

Tags: macos, xcode, development

On the command line I can use `clang -std=c++98 -pedantic-errors` which will prevent me from using features of newer C++ versions.

How can I achieve the same thing with Xcode?

**EDIT**: Example code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    for(int& e : arr) {
        std::cout << e * e;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my desired behavior.

```
$ clang -std=gnu++98 main.cpp -pedantic-errors
main.cpp:5:16: error: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension [-Werror,-Wc++11-extensions]
    for(int& e : arr) {
               ^
1 error generated.
```

But running Xcode with the c++98 toolchain set doesn't error.

**EDIT 2**: I found a switch to make it warn, but it Xcode doesn't error.
[image: xcode disable c++11 extensions]

**EDIT 3:** I found another switch to make warnings errors
[image: warnings to errors]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click on a Project file, then Build Settings and find C++ Language Dialect.

[image: C++ Language Dialect in Xcode]

Use this to get an error:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I updated my question. I've updated the C++ dialect to use c++98 but I'm still able to use, my example, range based for-loops.